# Auto Description From Tags

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I'm trying to generate auto description from tags.
The code was working but after updating my site to Laravel 6 in stop working. I need to get it back working.

```
if( !empty( $request->description ) )
{
    $description = Helper::checkTextDb($request->description);
}
else
{
    $a_key = explode(",", strtolower($request->tags));
    if(count($a_key) == 0)
        $description = 'This is a great thing';
    else
    {
    $description_get_keys = '';
        foreach ($a_key as &$value)
        {
            if($value == end($a_key) && count($a_key) != 1)
                $description_get_keys = $description_get_keys.' and '.$value.'.';
            else if(count($a_key) == 1)
                $description_get_keys = $value.'.';
            else if (count($a_key) > 1 && $a_key[0] == $value)
                $description_get_keys = $value;
            else
                $description_get_keys = $description_get_keys.', '.$value;
        }
    $description = 'This is a great thing about '.$description_get_keys;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple things that could possibly be an issue, not knowing what came before this code.

I will assume that the `$request` variable is an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request` and that it is available in the function, right?

Try this updated code:

```php
if($request->has('description'))
{
    $description = Helper::checkTextDb($request->description);
}
else if ($request->has('tags'))
{
    if (strpos($request->tags, ',') === false)
    {
        $description = 'This is a great thing';
    }
    else {
        $a_key = explode(",", strtolower($request->tags));
        $a_count = count($a_key);

        $description_get_keys = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $a_count; $i++)
        {
            if ($a_count == 1) {
                $description_get_keys = "{$a_key[$i]}.";
            }
            else {
                // first
                if ($i === 0) {
                    $description_get_keys = $a_key[0];
                }
                // last
                else if ($i === $a_count - 1) {
                    $description_get_keys .= " and {$a_key[$i]}.";
                }
                // middle
                else {
                    $description_get_keys .= ", {$a_key[$i]}";
                }
            }
        }

        $description = "This is a great thing about {$description_get_keys}";
    }
}
```

I wrote that quick so hopefully there are no errors.